# How to use TimeAgoPipe of MomentModule from typescript file in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe, angular2-moment

I want to use moment.js for displaying the age of a marker shown in google map in my ionic 2 app. I have installed moment.js as

```
npm install --save angular2-moment
```

The doc of angular2-moment explains how to use amTimeAgo from template. But I couldn't find anything about using it from type script file. So I decided to try it myself.

First I imported TimeAgo pipe in my app.module.ts and provided it

```
import { TimeAgoPipe } from "angular2-moment";

...........

providers: [
   .............
   TimeAgoPipe
]
```

But when I create a constructor of this TimeAgoPipe as below by importing this file in a component I get the following error.

CODE :

```
import { TimeAgoPipe } from "angular2-moment";
...........
constructor(private timeAgoPipe: TimeAgoPipe) {}
```

ERROR :

`Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for ChangeDetectorRef`

Answer (score -2):

You need to add

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
```

In module and provide it.

Comment: Where should I add it? app.module.ts?

Comment: Yes, in app.module.ts

Comment: still showing same error

Comment: You add ChangeDetectorRef in providers?

Comment: unable to add ChangeDetectorRef in provider. It showing error when I am adding it to provider.

Comment: Ok, remove import ChangeDetectorRef. Try to move TimeAgoPipe from providers to declarations

Comment: When I moved TimeAgPipe from providers to declaration I get the following error : Uncaught Error: Type TimeAgoPipe is part of the declarations of 2 modules: MomentModule and AppModule! Please consider moving TimeAgoPipe to a higher module that imports MomentModule and AppModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes TimeAgoPipe then import that NgModule in MomentModule and AppModule.

Comment: Moment module include TimeAgPipe, then you can use it without import

Comment: How do i use TimeAgoPipe without importing it

Comment: Try to import TimeAgPipe in component , and use it

Comment: Now app is not showing any error during the initialization of TimeAgoPipe, but I am unable to use transform method of TimeAgoPipe variable. It returns the error - TypeError: Cannot call method 'transform' of undefined

Comment: It worked for me when I used momen.js rather than angular2moment by following the tutorial -
 https://medium.com/@jek.bao.choo/steps-to-add-moment-js-to-angular-cli-f9ab28e48bf0

Comment: @DijishU.K Using moment directly is exactly what is suggested in duplicate question. You won't be able to use the pipe directly for the reasons mentioned there, neither you should.

Comment: Importing something in your `AppModule` won't do anything at all, also, you shouldn't have to provide the ChangeDetectorRef, there is most likely something else wrong in the OP